# Python - get line count of a file via ftp

Tags: python, ftp, ftplib

I am trying to use ftplib to count the number of lines in a file. This is what I have come up with so far.

```
ftp = FTP('ftp2.xxx.yyy')
ftp.login(user='xxx', passwd='yyy')
count = 0
def countLines(s):
    nonlocal count
    count += 1
    x=str(s).split('\\r')
    count += len(x)

ftp.retrbinary('RETR file_name'], countLines)
```

But the line count is off by a few ( I get about 20 more ), How can I fix it / Is there a better simpler solution

Comment: If your countLines comes up short, then you could try splitting by '\n'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use [`FTP.retrlines`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ftplib.html#ftplib.FTP.retrlines), not `FTP.retrbinary`.

```
count = 0
def countLines(s):
    global count
    count += 1

ftp.retrlines('RETR file_name', countLines)
```

---

For `FTP.retrbinary`:

> The `callback` function is called for each **block of data** received

While for `FTP.retrlines`:

> The `callback` function is called for each **line** with a string argument containing the line with the trailing CRLF stripped.

---

With `FTP.retrbinary` you get more, because if a block ends in a middle of a line, that line is counted twice.

Comment: Awesome, I cant believe I missed it.

Answer (score 1):

As suggested, use `FTP.retrlines`, but if you must use `FTP.retrbinary`, you will need to count on *only* each "\n", and not with each callback as well.

```
import ftplib

class FTPLineCounter(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.count = 0

    def __call__(self, file_text):
        """Count the lines as the file is received"""
        self.count += file_text.count(b"\n")



ftp = ftplib.FTP("localhost")
ftp.login()

counter = FTPLineCounter()

ftp.retrbinary("RETR file_name", counter)

print(counter.count)
```

Comment: You need something like `self.count += file_text.count("\n")` - Though you will still miss the last line, if it is not terminated with CRLF.